# Why this Basis Parabolic PDE's solution is not smooth?

Tags: differential-equations, scripting

What is this Parabolic PDE modeling in real life? Why the solutions is not nice? Have I made any coding errors?

$\frac{\partial u(t,x)}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 u(t,x)}{\partial x^2}$

$\frac{\partial u(t,0)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u(t,1)}{\partial x}=0$, $u(0,x)=3$

`Du=0.1;`

`usol = NDSolve[{D[uind[t,x],t]==Du*D[uind[t,x],x,x], (D[uind[t,x],x]/.x->0) == 0,(D[uind[t,x],x]/.x->1) == 0, uind[0,x]==3},{uind},{t,0,10},{x,0,1}];`

`Plot3D[{Evaluate[uind[t,x]]/.usol[[1,1]]},{t,0,10},{x,0,1},PlotRange->All,AxesLabel->{"t","x","Sol"},  ImageSize -> Dynamic[size, (size = Large)]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what is `Du` ? What is `X`

This is basic heat pde on a pipe with both its ends insulated and the pipe having initial temperature of 3. It describes how the temperature changes with time and space inside the pipe.

Since both ends are insulated, and since there is no heat source, the solution is expected to be the same as initial conditions for all time. i.e. `u->3` should be the solution.

Always write the pde, IC, BC as separate lines to make the code easier to read. No need to cramp everything in one line.

```
ClearAll[uind, x, t];
Du = 1; (*use 1 for heat diffusion constant for now *)
pde = D[uind[t, x], t] == Du*D[uind[t, x], x, x];
bc = {(D[uind[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) == 0, (D[uind[t, x], x] /. x -> 1) == 0};
ic = uind[0, x] == 3;

usol = NDSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, uind, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 1}]

Plot3D[{Evaluate[uind[t, x]] /. usol}, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"t", "x", "Sol"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to analytical solution

```
 usol = DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, uind[t, x], {t, x}]
 (* {{uind[t, x] -> 3}} *)
```

> Why the solutions is not nice?

Where exactly is the problem? If you mean why numerical solution is not exactly `3` at edges of pipe initially but it is 2.9999 and 3.0002? Well, I guess because this is numerical solution and not exact where it should be `3` everywhere. This could be how it approximated `u` at `x=0` and `x=1` at `t=0`. May be it used first order approximation there to find `u` at these points initially.

But notice the numerical solution becomes `3` exactly everywhere at `t>0`.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Yes, Du is the diffusion constant and X (constant) is the right end of the spatial variable x. Is everyone downvoting because of missing constants?